# Blazor and SSE (Server-Sent Events)

Tags: blazor, server-sent-events

is possible to implement use Server-Sent Events in blazor apps? Or there is other method to listening for request/response to API?

```
<script>
    source = new EventSource('/Home/Messaggio');
    source.onopen = function (ddd) {
        console.log("aperta");
    };
    source.onerror = function (ddd) {
        console.log("errore");
        console.log(ddd.data);
        source.close();
    };

    source.onmessage = function (ddd) {
        $("#Messaggio").text(ddd.data);
        console.log(ddd.data);
    };
</script>
```

Is method to get data in javascript code and add the data to C# blazor variable List responseObject?

Answer (score 2):

.Net (and therefore Blazor) provides a standard library called SignalR that abstracts the main "bidirectional communication technologies": Long polling, SSE, Websocket...etc. That means you don't need to deal with SSE, Websockets...etc. Just use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Update:

Since your server does not use SignalR, I suggest you write (or import) a Javascript SSE client to communicate with the server, then use [JSInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to pass the results to your C# code.

Comment: My blazor appl connect to external application where is SSE used. Is possible to receive by signalR events sending as SSE by server?

Comment: @cadi2108 I don't think there is a straightforward way to use SignalR on the client side only, since the server is not implemented with SignalR. What you can do is that you can either try to find an SSE client written in C# (I don't think there is anything standard, there are [third party libraries](https://github.com/3ventic/EvtSource)). Or you can do the work in javascript and use [JSInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to pass the data to your C# code.

Comment: Thanks, I used informations in article https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/ and now it's working. Add please as second answer suggestion about JSInterop and I will mark it as accepted answer.