Blazer Server Side events
I am new to Blazor (Server Side) and in my prototypes I was wondering, if it is possible to trigger server side events (As there is always an open connection between client and server, maybe there is a native way to do that in the latest version 8).
I'd like to implement a sample use case, where a user edits some metadata about a person in a Blazor/Razor form. At the same time, another user starts to edit that person and both forms get updated. So both can see the changes from the other user (like known from Google Docs or Office 365).
In my research, most recommendations are about SignalR, as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000071/1099519
In the updated version of this Stackoverflow article, there is also the link to JSRuntime.
Is there a native way in Blazor (server side) or do I need to use another technology, what would you recommend for that?

There is of course a package to do just that.

You could try following sample using signalR which may meet your demand.
Create a Blazor Web App template.

Install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
Create MyHub.cs
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SyncProfile", profile);
        }
    }

Profile.cs
    public class Profile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = ""; 
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    }

Add following to program.cs
...
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
...
app.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub");

Modify Home.razor with following codes:
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@implements IAsyncDisposable


Name:
<input @bind="profile.Name" @bind:after="SyncAll" />
<hr />
Email:
<input @bind="profile.Email" @bind:after="SyncAll" />


@code {
    private Profile profile = new Profile();

    private HubConnection? hubConnection;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/myhub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<Profile>("SyncProfile", (receivedProfile) =>
        {
            profile = receivedProfile;
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task SyncAll()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendProfile", profile);
        }
    }
}

Then run the project, open 2 window of the home page. The modifycation in either window will sync to each other.

Just note that this sample trigger "syncAll" when an input if finished. If you want trigger sync on typing, you could use "@onchange" event.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
